# Getting the print format modifier from the input

Tags: python-3.x

How can i get the print modifiers, such as %d from the user.

In the following example, the user specifies the value only (var):

```
var = 4
askQ = "%d" % var
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
var = 4
fmt = "%02d"
askQ = "????" % (fmt, var)
```

So that askQ becomes 04. Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use:

```
askQ = fmt % var
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
var = 4
fmt = '{:02d}'

print(fmt.format(var))
```

Prints:

```
04
```